# audio play/pause button problem in multiline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

we want make a audio toggle button play and pause like this script.
i have 15000 line and i want add every line audio button with different audio source.

[image]

i am using this source now if you gave me good suggestion or new script work for me thankful to you.
i want only one time save javascriptm, make change in html for every line.

if you want to check demo [visit now](http://islahemuashra.com/?page_id=5)

```js
 var count =0;
    document.getElementById("toggle-button").onclick = function() {

   
        if(count%2==0){
            document.getElementById("player2").play();
            document.getElementById("icons").classList.remove("fa-play-circle-o");
            document.getElementById("icons").classList.add("fa-pause-circle-o");
        }else{
            document.getElementById("player2").pause();
            document.getElementById("icons").classList.add("fa-play-circle-o");
            document.getElementById("icons").classList.remove("fa-pause-circle-o");
        }

        count++;
    }
```

```css
.d-table {
  display:table !important;
}

.d-table-cell {
  display:table-cell !important;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100% !important;
}
.w-10 {
  width: 8% !important;
}
.tar {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class=" d-table w-100">
<p class="d-table-cell">بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ</p>
  <div class="d-table-cell tar w-10">
 <audio id="player2" src="http://www.mp3naat.com/download/owais-raza-qadri/mustafa-jaan-e-rehmat.mp3"></audio>    
<a id="toggle-button"><i id="icons" class="fa  fa-play-circle-o fa-2x"></i></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the HTML contain elements having duplicate `id`s?

Comment: no dear its not have duplicate ids

Comment: What is the issue with the code?

Comment: if i add this code to first line,  its work ,  if same code add in second row with different audio source, second button is not work

Comment: Can you demonstrate the issue at stacksnippets?

Comment: please see the fiddle for demostrate https://jsfiddle.net/hgLxu3re/

Comment: The HTML contains elements having duplicate `id`s.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187703/discussion-between-scatter-instruments-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML contains duplicate `id`s. You can substitute `clsss` for `id` and use `.quesrySelectorAll()` and `.forEach()` to attach `click` event to each element which plays or pauses `<audio>` element that is `e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling`. The CSS needs to be adjusted as to icon display and toggling.

HTML

```
<div class=" d-table w-100">
  <p class="d-table-cell">بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ</p>
  <div class="d-table-cell tar w-10">
    <audio class="player" src="http://www.mp3naat.com/download/owais-raza-qadri/mustafa-jaan-e-rehmat.mp3"></audio>
    <a class="toggle-button"><i class="icons" class="fa  fa-play-circle-o fa-2x">play</i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class=" d-table w-100">
  <p class="d-table-cell">بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ</p>
  <div class="d-table-cell tar w-10">
    <audio class="player" src="http://www.mp3naat.com/download/owais-raza-qadri/mein-jashn-e-aamad-e-sarkar.mp3"></audio>
    <a class="toggle-button"><i class="icons" class="fa  fa-play-circle-o fa-2x">play</i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
let toggleButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-button')
let handleToggle = e => {
  console.log(e.target);
  let audio = e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
  let icon = e.target.parentElement.firstElementChild;
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    icon.classList.remove("fa-play-circle-o");
    icon.classList.add("fa-pause-circle-o");
  } else {
    if (!audio.paused) {
      audio.pause();
      icon.classList.add("fa-play-circle-o");
      icon.classList.remove("fa-pause-circle-o");
    }
  }
}

toggleButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', handleToggle));
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8z9uq5kL/

Comment: thank you, its woking , 1 problem i see,   when audio is finished but pause button still show , its not show play button again  see the https://jsfiddle.net/hgLxu3re/2/

Comment: @ScatterInstruments You can attach `ended` event to each `<audio>` element and set the `class` of `<i>` element at event handler https://jsfiddle.net/x3c1upz9/